# How to use JavaScript inside ng-if AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was trying to use a `JavaScript` expression with `ng-if`. However, it didn't do anything. It allways returns `false`.

**What i tried was following:**

`ng-if="localStorage.getItem('grid-layout') == 'list'` *(if true, show div)*

The `div` doens't render, because it allways returns `false`. The grid-layout value is saved in the `localStorage`. This is not the issue.

I checked the documentation on the website. `Angular` says the following about `ng-if`

**https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf**

> If the expression is falsy then the element is removed from the DOM
>   tree. If it is truthy a copy of the compiled element is added to the
>   DOM tree.

Is it possible to use just `JavaScript` inside `ng-if`? If not, how can i archieve what i was trying to do?

Comment: Did you try to check `localStorage` for `null` or `undefined`? Maybe your problem here is that you cannot get hold of `localStorage` like this. Try `ng-if="localStorage"` then you can rule out this reason.

Comment: Yes, i checked it, it isset to the correct value. I checked it both with console.log and inside the devtools

Comment: Did you check inside html?

Comment: Why would i check it inside the HTML? If its saved i can access it everywhere.

Comment: Because it is probably not in the scope.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Javascript expression inside an ng-if, but you are only able to access properties that are in the `$scope` of the current template.

It's unlikely that `localStorage` would be available to you unless you had specifically added it to the `$scope` object.

One approach would be to write a function attached to the $scope in your controller:

```
//in controller JS
$scope.checkLocalStorage = function() {
    return localStorage.getItem('grid-layout') == 'list';
}

//In template
<div ng-if="checkLocalStorage()"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the awnser, well the problem with this is that i dont have any controller linked to that page. Only a directive. But the directive is called before it.

Comment: I can't add a controller to the page. But ive access to a root controller. So i did what u suggested there. It works! Thanks. I accept when SO lets me :)

Comment: Can I use === instead == ??

Answer (score 1):

Move your logic to the controller:

In HTML call method :

```
ng-if="checkForLocalStorage()"
```

and in controller, inject `$window` and write method like :

```
$scope.checkForLocalStorage = function(){
   return $window.localStorage.getItem('grid-layout') == 'list' 
}
```

**Further**, the better approach is to make boolean property in `controller`, and bind it to the `ng-if`. else your method will be called on every model\binding change because of angular digest cycle.

You can do do it like, In controller:

```
$scope.isGridLayoutList= $window.localStorage.getItem('grid-layout') == 'list' ;
```

and in HTML : `ng-if="isGridLayoutList"`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use localstorage inside the `ng-if` since `ng-if` is angular directive it only supports angular expression. one thing you can do is create a scope function and return the localstorage value

```
ng-if="getStorage() == 'list'"

$scope.getStorage = function(){
 return localStorage.getItem('grid-layout');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to store a function in `$scope` variable and call it in html. You can store the truthy/falsy value directly in a variable and use it in `ng-if`, Better and reduces lines of code

```
$scope.toShow = (localStorage.getItem('grid-layout') == 'list');

<div ng-if="toShow"></div>
```

Comment: Pretty unclear what you're trying to say. Whats LOC?